# I have two table that link with each other in SQL. But i can't figure out how to print one of table's data

Tags: database

Two table are Product and Category. I create a menu in the right allowing client to choose their wanted category by chosing list of CategoryName.But the menu show up many lines of recursive CategoryName, in fact, just two CategoryName are neccessary.

This is my main view

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<SportsStore.Domain.Concrete.Product>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

<div class="page-header">
    <h3>Danh sách sản phẩm</h3>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 category">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/_Category.cshtml", item.Category);
    }
</div> // this is my menu

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
    @foreach (var product in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 product">
            <a href="#" title="@product.ProductName">
                <div class="frame">
                    <img src="@product.ProductImage" class="img-responsive adaptor" />
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                    <h3>@product.ProductName</h3>
                </div>
                <strong>@product.Price $</strong>
                <div class="rate">
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star1"></i>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star2"></i>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star3"></i>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star4"></i>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star5"></i>
                            <span>(15 nhận xét)</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    }
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
    new { page }))
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/Rating.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

//This is my _Category, which i want to  to print out only two of CategoryName //instead of lines of recursive CategoryName:

```
@model SportsStore.Domain.Concrete.Category

<p>
    <a href="#">@Model.CategoryName</a>
</p>
```

I don't know how to do this ideally. I was tempted to add If clause in _Category to sort CategoryName. But i know i should not do the bussiness logic in View. If i choose @model PagedList.IPagedList instead of @model PagedList.IPagedList, it's rather wasted because i have to change my code every time i bring some new data to this view. Please help me

Comment: Where is there any SQL? Please retag your question with adequate tags.

Comment: @sticky bit. Ok, i did it, thanks for your concern.